# When applying for a Schengen visa, how do I prove that my employer/company will pay all my costs?

Tags: visas, schengen, filipino-citizens, saudi-arabia, proof-of-funds

I'm Filipino by nationality and have been working in Saudi Arabia for more than 3 years. I've already started working on the requirements for getting a Schengen visa. The company/employer will be the one who is paying all the cost for my travel and stay during my holiday. Is there any format for proving that my company/employer will shoulder the expenses for me?

Comment: Whom do you need proof for?

Comment: I suppose a visa requirement is to show you are able to pay for your stay? then if you have a written agreement with your company stating it pays for everything, attach it. I think that for this kind of document, a specific minimum amount is required, so make sure this agreement mentions how much your company will pay for: "everything" might be too vague.

Comment: Did you mean to tag this [tag:philippine-airlines]? Or should it be [tag:philippine-citizens]?

Answer (score 4):

As @Vence commented, a letter from your employer will be more than enough for the embassy/consulate. If that money will be cashed to you enough time before your flight then you can deposit it in your bank account and attach the bank statement to your visa request. Both of these scenarios will grant you the visa.